# Javascript Date is adding a month

Tags: javascript, date

Javascript's Date object is acting really strange.

If I create a new Date its always adding one month even from the browser console.

Here is an example:

```
date = new Date(2013, 06, 01)
Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
date = new Date(2013, 01, 01)
Fri Feb 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Any ideas of what is going on??

Comment: I think month starts from 0,1,2...11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) specification *month* is integer between 0-11

> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 3):

javascript dates have 0 indexed months, so you need to use 0 for january up to 11 for december

```
date = new Date(2013, 00, 01)
Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```